# parsing float into string

Tags: c#, string, floating-point

I have a number like so: 4.47778E+11

Can anyone give me a way of converting that into its number representation easily in c#?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string s = "4.47778e+11";
double d = double.Parse(s);
```

or

```
string s = "4.47778e+11";
if (double.TryParse(s,out d))
{
    // number was parsed correctly
}
```

or for internationalization

double.Parse("4.47778e+11", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: Better it would be 
double.Parse("4.47778e+11", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
since first example will fail eg. on Polish localization

Answer (score 0):

Try [this MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/e482cda0-6510-4d2c-b830-11e57e04f65d).  It's called scientific notation by the way, and a [quick google](http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=Xmw&q=C%23+parse+scientific+notation&btnG=Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=) normally solves simple issues.

That's assuming you mean parsing **from** a string **to** a float, your question & title are conflicting

Comment: Hi mryne, sorry the title was confusing. I have a csv file where people open it in excel and then save as csv, the string representation is a large number, but excel will convert by default into scientific notation. My title should have been clearer!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
float num = Convert.ToFloat(Convert.ToDouble(s));
```

But you still lose precision, floats are only precise to 7 digits, so you're better off using just the Convert.ToDouble() (precise to 15 or so digits), so you won't lose any digits in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Use Convert:

```
double value = Convert.ToDouble("4.47778E+11");
```